# i'm having some problem with saveing the vaule of the longest fence

Tags: c

[image]

I'm having some problem with saveing the vaule of the longest fence.

I tried this:

```
int longestFence(char input [], int size)
{
    int i , max = 0, count = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size ; i++)
    {
        if(input[i] == '|'  && input[i] == '-')
        {
            count = 1;
        }
        if(input[i] != input[i + 1])
        {
            count++ - 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! We would ask you to always post text, not screenshots of text. Also, please be so kind to make your example code *complete*, so that anyone can copy, paste, compile & run your example (without additional edits) to see what you are seeing. This really helps with helping you. ;-) Personally, I would also prefer when homework questions are somehow marked as such, because they would require a different kind of answer.

Comment: So you tried something and you show us that code. Now what do you expect from us?

Comment: `input[i] == '|'  && input[i] == '-'` -- That can never be true, because `input[i]` can't be both a pipe and a dash. This: `input[i] != input[i + 1]` is illegal when `i + 1== size`.

Comment: (In such cases, it can be easier to keep the previous character in a variable. Then you can decide based on the current and the previous character whether the fence continues. By the way, you never need to decrease the length, you only ever increase it or reset it to zero. But you should keep track of the longest length so far.)

Answer (score 2):

In practice, to detect is the fence is still valid, you just have to check if the current symbol is different or not than the previous one.

You also have to check if the current count is longer or not than the previous longest one.

Besides, I modified the random string generator: the current one is rather inefficient.

In addition, the string generated is not terminated by the Null character. I also modified it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX 10

int longestFence (char input[], int size) {
    if (size == 0) return 0;
    int max_count = 0;
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        if (input[i] != input[i-1]) {
            count++;
        } else {
            if (count > max_count) max_count = count;
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    if (count > max_count) max_count = count;
    return max_count;
}

int main() {
    char string[MAX+1];
    char symbols[] = {'|', '-'};
    srand (time(NULL));
    int length = rand() % (MAX+1);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        int val = (rand() / 16) % 2;
        string[i] = symbols[val];
    }
    string[length] = '\0';
    printf ("String is: %s\n", string);
    printf ("Longest fence = %d\n", longestFence (string, length));
    return 0;
}
```